# fancybox 2 with div

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I thought I had trouble using fancybox 2 with nivo slider wrapped by a div, but after some tests, I found that i have trouble using facybox 2 with div. So I will reorganize my question.
To make it clearer, I will post my codes in the following:

For css:

```
<style>
  #content{
    background: red;
  }
  #maximize{ width: 24px; height: 24px; }
</style>
```

For html:

```
<a href='#content' id="maximize"> max </a>
<div id="content"> </div>
```

For JS:

```
$('#maximize').click(function() {
$('#maximize').fancybox({
     'href' : '#content'
   });
});
```

It works as expected if I clicked the max button.  However, if I closed the fancybox, the popup box is gone, and the original div with id = "content" disappear as well. this is not expected. I want the content become what it was, but not disappeared.

Other question: How can I change the size of the fancy box popped up? I want to make the fancy box larger.

I hope my question is clear enough. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If fancybox opens the `div` with `id="slider-wrapper"`, then it shouldn't be `$("#slider-wrapper").show()` inside the callback `afterClose`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need :

```
$('#maximize').click(function() {
   $('#maximize').fancybox({
     'href' : '#content'
   });
});
```

... but only this :

```
$('#maximize').fancybox({
    // API options here
});
```

... since `.fancybox()` already binds the `click` event to the selector `#maximize`, otherwise is redundant .... so does the `'href' : '#content'` option since the `href` is already taken from the `href` attribute in the link.

On the other hand, fancybox will always hide the opened `inline` content since it would be its expected state (isn't it redundant to show in fancybox something that is already visible?) ... anyway, you could make it visible again using the callback `afterClose` like :

```
$('#maximize').fancybox({
    afterClose: function() {
        $("#content").show();
    }
});
```

Regarding the second question, use the `width` and `height` options along with `fitToView` and `autoSize` to set your preferred box dimensions like :

```
$('#maximize').fancybox({
    fitToView: false, // avoid the adjusting size to viewport
    autoSize: false, // avoid set size based on content
    width: 420, // or whatever
    height: 320,
    afterClose: function() {
        $("#content").show();
    }
});​
```

See **[working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/F8kaS/)**